# Can lambda expressions capture CV-qualified variables?

Tags: c++, lambda

In the following snippet, `_filewatcher` is a const-qualified lvalue reference. I would like to compare it with every member of `m_files`, using their `getPath()` member function. Unfortunately this member function can only be called on `const` objects. This led me to write this code:

```
ErrorCode DirectoryWatcherWindows::addMonitoredFile(const FileWatcherWindows& _fileWatcher)
{
    ErrorCode ret = Success;

    auto iter = std::find_if(m_files.begin(), m_files.end(),            
        [&](FileWatcherWindows* fileWatcher)
        {   
            return _fileWatcher.getPath() == fileWatcher->getPath();
        }
    );

    if (iter == m_files.end())
        m_files.push_back(&_fileWatcher);
    else
        ret = AlreadyExists;

    return ret;
}
```

This does not compile under MSVC10, as `_fileWatcher` inside the lambda expression is not const-qualified. I have tried changing the capture field to `[const&]` but this would not work either.

Is there any way to have CV-qualified references in captures?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem: Capturing by reference captures whatever you want, but of course the reference will have the same CV-qualification as the original object. In your example, `_fileWatcher` is a const reference, so it's captured as const, too, and you mustn't change it.